# Path to Menu PHP File in WordPress Hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I am using wordpress to create a website for a client. In retrospect it maybe wasn't the correct platform. However lately every time I try to save my Menu via the CMS Menu I get presented with the 'White Screen of Death'

After Googleing it I am pretty sure it is because I am hitting my PHP memory limit as I have ruled out all other options. I can not alter the PHP.ini file on the server I am on.

So my question is, where is the PHP file that actually gets written to when you use the WordPress CMS Menu builder? Simple question if anyone knows it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about a plugin? Or are you talking about the Appearance -> Menu page in the admin panel? Menu items are posts, so they occupy only one row in a MySQL database. MySQL databases can easily handle tens of thousands of rows. And PHP won't load those items into memory when you write to the database?

Comment: I am talking about the Appearance > Menu option. And ok, I will check my DB for them now. I am unsure why this error occurs then, because my other Menus save fine, its just the biggest one (Main Navigation) that gives a white screen and doesn't save. and it only happened why I put a lot of links into it, in sub menus and such

Comment: Enable error logging in config.php - will help alot (define('WP_DEBUG', true);)

Answer (score 0):

You should have at least 64MB PHP-memory, does the webserver have any security modules like mod_security? Check the Server-Logs